# Perform WHERE 'field' IN (list) query in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

To every question, there are many answers. I have a table Vote which contains the upvote/downvotes on all the question and answers. I want to perform a query something like:

> Select * from vote WHERE username="some username" AND (QID="question"
>   OR (AID IN (SELECT AID from Answers WHERE QID="question")))

```
class Question(models.Model):
    QID = models.CharField( default="",max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1055, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    AID = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="", primary_key=True)
    QID = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=None)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1055, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.AID

class Vote(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=None)
    QID = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    AID = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.QID is not None:
            return self.QID.QID+'_'+self.username.username+'_'+str(self.vote)
        else:
            return self.AID.AID+'_'+self.username.username+'_'+str(self.vote)
```

P.S. Please note that QID and AID are foreign keys. So they will take instance of Question/Answer Model only.

Answer (score 1):

You could do,

```
from django.db.models import Q

Vote.objects.filter(username='some_username').filter(
                        Q(QID=question_id) |
                        Q(AID__QID=question_id
                        )
```

NOTE : Totally agree with @schillingt's answer.

Or, if you want to get all the `Vote` objects of a question, then you could call the reverse relation like,

```
question = Question.objects.get(QID='some_id')
question.vote_set.all()
```

Comment: What is the significance of this part, `.values_list('AID', flat=True)`

Comment: values_list() returns a list of field values of objects in the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this would be:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Vote.objects.filter(username='some_username').filter(
    Q(QID=question_id) |
    Q(AID___QID=question_id)
)
```

It avoids the additional query in Fazil Zaid's answer that's required to get the Answer ids for a given question id by doing that within the single query.